# How to combine JavaEE backend with Play framework?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am creating a new web application where I am using JPA, EJB and all the goodnes from JavaEE. However, I have been doing some JSF in the past (yes the latest version) and I personally don't like that much. So I have been introduced to Play Framework which is pretty awesome from what I have read so far. Now I want to use the Java EE backend with the Play framework. How would you do that? In order to use EJBs etc you need a EJB container and all that is provided by servers such as Glassfish, JBoss etc and Play framework use Netty (if I am correct). So how would you make these technologies talk together? Webservice (REST), RMI...?

And would the performance/lag be very high? I will have both servers running on the same VPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play 1.x (which I suspect that you would be since it sounds like you are looking to use Java, not Scala?), then you could use the [Play Spring Module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/spring).

I have not personally used this module with Play, I have stuck with the out-of-the-box structure (which uses JPA, btw).

Comment: As an aside, the Struts2 REST plugin (http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html) offers some great convention-over-configuration, pretty URLs, JSP + OGNL templating instead of JSF, and integrates easily with Spring (http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html) and your desired architecture.  In conjunction with the Bootstrap plugin (http://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/), you can throw a slick app over night.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you'll have two options:

1. Use an embeddable EJB container and start it in the [Play 2.0 Global.onStart()](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaGlobal). It exists these kinds of containers for various Java EE servers ([JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EJB31Embeddable), [Glassfish](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/) etc...)
2. Use webservices served from your Java EE app, but it will add a new "layer", and it should be slower.